# Getting the Binding object in the hyperlinkbutton - click event?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have a ListBox with a binding to an ObservableCollection of type MyViewModel. The item template is a HyperLinkButton. Is there a way to pass the MyViewModel to the HyperLinkButton.Click - event? The event has 2 parameters, object sender and RoutedEventArgs. The sender is of type HyperLinkButton and I does not have any reference to the Binding object at all! Is there a way to add MyViewModel as a parameter to the click event?

Thanks

Comment: Without more context I can't be sure of what you want to do, but from what I read, you might want to look at the Hyperlink's [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.command(v=vs.95).aspx) property. Using commands should allow you to access your view model in a more proper manner than going through event handlers.

Comment: madd0; Abgree regarding using Commands! If the project was bigger and more complex I would go down that path.

Comment: ok, but why do you need a bigger project to use commands? it barely takes any effort at all to use them instead of using events...

Comment: You are right madd0. I Should use Commands for any projects. The thing is that this is the only place I will need it so it felt a little overkill introducing commands, but you are right; no projects are too small for it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Property `CommandParameter` should do the job.

```
<HyperLinkButton Click="ClickEvent" CommandParameter={Binding} />
```

This should work because it will use the current MyViewModel which is binded to it. Then you simply need to access it in the event args. There is also an alternative. You can obtain the DataContext from the sender which is the HyperLinkButton. Which directs you to the MyViewModel instance. Hope this helps

Edit: Seems kinda wierd you dont have an object reference in your HyperLinkButton. U sure it is not the datacontext you need from it?